Horizontal page scrolling for ebook reading in flutter?
I am trying to make simple book reading app and having problems with implementing horizontal page scrolling. My first idea was to use PageView widget, but for this I should have predefined pages,so I should calculate how much text I could fit in a current page.
I am using .getPositionForOffset() method of TextPainer class that takes offset and returns index of closest character at that offset. So by using height and width of the screen, minus top and left paddings as offset coordinates, I should get the rightmost corner of the page, get the index of character at the righmost corner and then slice my String which contains book's contents and append these chunks to pages array. Then I could use this array in PageView.builder(). This is the code that implements this logic:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

const String longText = """imagine really long text here"""; 

List<String> pages = [];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: TextArea(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 20,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextArea extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextArea({
    super.key,
    required this.height,
    required this.width,
  });
  final double height;
  final double width;

  @override
  State<TextArea> createState() => _TextAreaState();
}

class _TextAreaState extends State<TextArea> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    calculateTextOnPage();
  }

  void calculateTextOnPage() {
    String remainingText = longText;

    while (remainingText.isNotEmpty) {
      // Set up the TextPainter for each chunk of longText
      final textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(text: remainingText,),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      );

      // Layout text within the constraints of the container
      textPainter.layout(maxWidth: widget.width);

      // Get the index of the character at the rigtmost of the TextArea
      int endIndex = textPainter.getPositionForOffset(Offset(widget.width, widget.height)).offset;


      // Extract the chunk of text that fits the page
      String chunk = remainingText.substring(0, endIndex);

      // Add the chunk to the list of pages
      pages.add(chunk);

      // Cut this chunk out of original text 
      remainingText = remainingText.substring(endIndex);
    }

    setState(() {}); 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      itemCount: pages.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey.shade200,
          ),
          child: SelectableText(pages[index]),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


Everything works as described, but endIndex gets wrong characters. As you can see in the image, this getting index at offset method misses by almost six lines. Any ideas why? I whought this maybe TextAreas height is not the same as PageView containers height, but I am passing container's height to offset anyway. I am so stuck  height and width constraints

"I am using .getPositionForOffset()" - use getBoxesForSelection() instead to get all the boxes of your text - getPositionForOffset could return the position of partially hidden line
